# How do I convert a string to a HTML tag with a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-2.0

I want to convert a Markdown string written with a custom syntax (my own; I'm creating my own markdown tag) into an HTML tag using regular expressions. I'm using a redcarpet custom renderer.

```
# From
[image:left:xyz]
[xyz]: http://foo.com

# To
<img src="http://foo.com" class="left">
```

I started writing a regular expression, but I found it very hard. I realize I'm trying to run before I walk, but regular expressions are really hard, and even while trying to learn them this problem might take me days.

A major issue is the second argument, in this case `left`, which maps to the image class attribute: it can also be `right`, `full`, or `spread`.

Another issue is that there might be several strings, not just one:

```
string.gsub \A\[(image)(:left)|(:right)(:id) do
  image_tag $1, class: $2 # not sure how to match $1, and $2...
end
```

Comment: What kind of markdown is that? Did you consider using existing md parsers?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing my own custom syntax.

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be quite complex, but this is something you could start with:

```
string = '[image:left:xyz]
[xyz]: http://foo.com

[image:right:yzx]
[yzx]: http://foo.com'

urls = {}

string.gsub!(/\[([^:]*)\]: (.*)\s?$/) do
  urls[$1] = $2 # grabbing all urls and their ids
  ''            # replacing them with empty string
end

string.gsub!(/\[image:(.*):(.*)\]/) do
  css_class = $1
  url       = urls[$2]

  image_tag(url, class: css_class)
end

string # =>
# <img src='http://foo.com' class='left' />

# <img src='http://foo.com' class='right' />
```

Feel free to ask for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
string.gsub!(/\[image:(left|right|full|spread):([^\]]+)\]\s*\[\2\]:\s*(\S+)/,'<img src="\3" class="\1"/>')
puts string
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to want to know about are REGEX Capture groups.

Put a bunch of your tags into [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and run a regex against them, that seems to be the fastest way to manage to find things out. I often use it whenever I need to get through a difficult REGEX of any kind.